# Neo4j - Error while cypher-querying nodes using full-text index in browser

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Let me tell my use-case with full text Index:

I want to find nodes with similar values inside a property.

I am facing this error while querying nodes using full text index -

Query:

```
MATCH (e: Email)
WITH e
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('convEmailFtIndex', e.convEmail)
YIELD node, score
RETURN e.email, node.convEmail, node.email, score ORDER BY e.email LIMIT 1000
```

Error:

```
ERROR
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed
Failed to invoke procedure db.index.fulltext.queryNodes: Caused by: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column. 0.
Was expecting one of:
...
"+"...
"-"...
...
"(" ...
"*"...
...
...
...
...
...
"["...
"{"...
...
...
```

I have this property called convEmail in my email which is basically only the alphabets of an email id, excluding numbers and special characters.

This is how I created the full-text index:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex('convEmailFtIndex', ['Email'], ['convEmail'], {analyzer: 'standard-no-stop-words'});
```

It would be very helpful if someone can help me resolve this. Thank you.

Comment: Please give us sample data to work on. Thanks.

Comment: one of e.convEmail should contain bad characters for the lucene query